# Iterate over a webelement obtained using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
rows = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@style='display: block;']//table[@style='display: table;']//tr")
```

When I try to iterate over rows It throws an error `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable`

```
def get_size(e):

   for  entry in e:

     count = count + 1
   return count

get_size(rows)
```

Comment: `type` will tell you the type of the object (Well, actually, you already know it's a `WebElement`.) and `dir` will help you figure out what methods are available. That might be a good place to start.

Comment: Your problem is that `find_element_by_xpath()` returns a single result.  You need `find_elements_by_xpath()` if you want a collection of results.

Answer (score 15):

Try this . This should work. use `find_elements_by_xpath`

```
Listlinker = []
Listlinker = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(""//div[@style='display: block;']//table[@style='display: table;']//tr")
for link in Listlinker:
// more code
```

Comment: If it helped you Please font forget to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Nice answer. Must have seen this many times, however never caught the difference with plural "elements" before this.